# invoking a command line tool from within by java applciation

Tags: java, windows, linux, macos, command-line

I have a command line tool that I want to launch from a java application. My application should then wait for the command line tool to return/finish.
I will deploy my application on windows, mac and linux and my app should be able to invoke the command line tool on every platform.
How can I properly invoke it from my java application?

Comment: Is it one single "command line tool" that is available on all OS, or different tools for each one?

Answer (score 6):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: I would also recommend reading & implementing all the suggestions of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  The linked article covers common traps when dealing with a `Process`.

Answer (score 1):

Use java.lang.Process for that:

```
    final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("yourprogram", null, outputDir);
    final int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    if (exitCode != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("program didnt exit with 0, but with " + exitCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Runtime` class to start command line program.  You should be able to use in Win/Mac/Linux by making sure that the command line program you are running is always in the PATH.

```
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc;               
            proc = rt.exec(cmdName);

            // Wait for the command to complete.
            exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```